# Hadoop FileUtil copymerge - Ignore header

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

While writing out from spark to HDFS, depending upon the header setting, each file has a header. So when calling copymerge in FileUtil we get duplicated headers in merged file. Is there a way to retain header from 1st file and ignore others.

Comment: I usually use a combination of `hdfs dfs -getmerge` and `sed` in case you're planning to bring the file to a UNIX edge node.

Comment: @philantrovert Can you please share example for same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to merge it as a single file and then fetch it on to your local file system, you can use [`getmerge`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge).

> ### getmerge
>
> Usage: `hadoop fs -getmerge [-nl] <src> <localdst>`
>
> Takes a source directory and a destination file as input and concatenates files in src into the destination local file. Optionally -nl can be set to enable adding a newline character (LF) at the end of each file. -skip-empty-file can be used to avoid unwanted newline characters in case of empty files.

Now to remove the headers, you should have an idea of how your header looks like.

Suppose if your header looks like:

```
HDR20171227
```

You can use:

```
sed -i '1,${/^HDR/d}' "${final_filename}"
```

where `final_filename` is the name of the file on local FS.

This will delete all lines that start with `HDR` in your file and occur after the first line.

If you are unsure about the header, you can first store it in a variable using

```
header=$(head -1 "${final_filename}" )
```

And then proceed to delete it using `sed`.